# predict more than one variable with training data

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, predictive-models

Considering we have four predict variables:`x1,x2,x3,x4` and three response variables:`y1,y2,y3`. After learning the relationship between response and predict variables with training data, I want to obtain the `y1,y2,y3` for any new given `x1,x2,x3,x4`.
What methods can deal with this question?

Comment: This is called *supervised learning*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope I can be anyhow helpful as to my view you provide quite a broad ground for a discussion. From the information provided how about Vector Autoregressive Models (VAR) as you are interested in vector of dependent variables? They seem to be designed to produce forecasts for multiple variables and are often used and available within most statistical packages. Please see R package [here](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/vars/vars.pdf) that might be appropriate for your goals.

I am not sure how it is from the theoretical side but I think you can avoid ARMA structure which is common for such models and use input which you desire (as you use different notation for your independent input). In case if you have time-series data ARMA can be actually helpful and can be supplemented with your input (x1,x2,x3 etc. if using your notation). Hope that helps.